# How to compare to older commits in TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I want to compare my latest commit with one of the older commits, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Using the TFS web interface, I go to code-> History and click the latest commit. This opens a summary of all changes compared to the Parent. I try to pick an older commit (other than the parent) from the "Showing diff to..." drop down, but there I can only choose the Parent, none of the older commits.

When I select an individual file in the commit I am able to compare to older commits, as long as the file is changed compared those commits. This really does not cover my needs since this would require me to know exactly which files that are modified browse my way to each file...

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this now in TFS:

1. **First, add a tag to the two commits** you want to compare. In this case, add a tag to the latest commit and to the older commit. (If you don't know how to do this, go to your list of commits in TFS, hover over the desired commit, click the ellipsis that appears, and hit "Create tag...".)
2. **Click on the "Tags" header** in TFS.
3. Hover over **the tag for the older commit**, click the ellipsis, and **click "Set as compare tag."**
4. Hover over **the tag for the newer/latest commit**, click the ellipsis, and **click "Compare Tags."**
5. **Click the "Compare" tab** at the top.

Done! You should now see a list of all the files that changed between commits with their changes highlighted, like in a pull request.

Comment: I just wanted to check the changes between two releases in a clear UI. This helped a lot!

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Within Visual Studio you can compare the latest commit to any older commit for a *single* file, and within TFS web interface you can get a unified diff of *all* files in the latest commit compared to the second most recent commit, but I do not think either interface lets you do both (i.e. seeing a unified diff of all files in a commit against an arbitrary earlier commit).

Part of the reason for that, I would think, is that it is not clear what it means to select a *single* earlier commit when talking about multiple files. Referring to the figure showing commits starting at changeset 10384 up to the latest, 10393. Changeset 10393 contains the three files indicated.

[image: commit history]

When you view a unified diff in TFS web interface, what you are actually seeing is:

- File 1: 10393 compared to 10391
- File 2: 10393 compared to 10389
- File 3: 10393 compared to 10387

Now say you want to compare the latest commit (10393) to 10389. That's fine for file1 and file 2, but technically file 3 does not exist in commit 10389. In practice, though, I think that using the specified version or earlier would be very reasonable behavior, so the system should search back from there and find changeset 10387 for file 3.

So that is not a huge problem to overcome to my mind and I agree that being able to see a unified diff against earlier commits would be a very helpful feature indeed!

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the diff between 2 commits using git with tfs by selecting both commits, right click and compare. I will show you using vs2013

- Step 1: go to history and select 2 versions of the file you want to compare by clicking with ctrl key pressed
  [STEP 1 PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpAkA.png)
- Step 2: right click on the selected versions and compare
  [STEP 2 PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vi2P.png)
- Step 3: Compare the files. xD
  [STEP 3 PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWQul.png)

I hope this to be useful to you.

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to clone the repo first